# How to add subview with half-transparent background which won't break and won't be affected by AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I want to show user that application is loading data using some progress bar and label on top of view which will be shown after the data is loaded. This view is not initial, so I cannot use LaunchScreen for these purposes. What's the best way to do so?

The view which will be shown after uses AutoLayout, and it'd better be that view on top uses AutoLayout as well, but those AutoLayouts shouldn't interact with each other in any way.

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom UIView class, and customize the view according to your requirement. i.e. transparent background, add image/label etc. using autolayout/with the help of code.

Now add this custom view (yourSubView) into its containerview and add some constraint so that it place in right location.

The following code will add a subview after keep space 80px in all side (left, right, top, bottom), you can add constraint according to your requirement.

```
    [yourContainerView addSubview:yourSubView];
    yourSubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =
    NO;

    [yourContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:yourContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0]];
    [yourContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:yourContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0]];
    [yourContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:yourContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0]];
    [yourContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:yourContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like https://github.com/sgryschuk/SGNavigationProgress?